# Lookup-Filter Classic to Lightning

Tags: lookup-filter

I have ran the release readiness report to identify what gaps I need to consider for moving from Classic to Lightning and I have profiles that need to have some work addressed, one of which is Lookup Filters.  What do i need to do to clear this item?

Answer (score 0):

I think lookup filter works in Lightning as well. Salesforce had fixed it in spring 17 release
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000E0bEAAS